# Why is there a disconnect between innovation index and Nobel prizes won?

Tags: technology, science

I'm seeing the [innovation index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Innovation_Index) wikipedia and the [Nobel prize by country list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Nobel_laureates_by_country). It seems to me Asian countries ranked high on the innovation index are ranked relatively lower compared to Asian countries on the Nobel prize list. Why?

Comment: Nobel laureates don't always win the Prize in the same year that they achieved whatever they earned it for. Charles K Kao invented fiber-optic communication in 1966 and didn't win the Nobel Prize for it until 2009. It's possible that this is a factor - the Innovation Index was published in 2009, so countries that were innovative then may not win Nobel Prizes for it until years down the line - but I'm not confident enough to make it an answer.

Comment: @F1Krazy That is exactly what I'm thinking. The most recent Nobel Prize for physics was for experiments made between 1974 and 1998 that showed Bell's inequality was true. Those three physicists are all old now. Scientific breakthroughs are almost always made by the young, where "young" means 45 or younger. People with well-aged flatulence (aka old farts) tend not to make breakthrough discoveries. The Nobel Prizes are for people with extremely well-aged flatulence whose discoveries / breakthroughs have been confirmed time and time again.

Comment: There's also the fact that Nobel Prizes for physics in particular are typically awarded for pure science, e.g. the physics prize goes to cosmologists, astrophysicists/astronomers, or theoretical physicists. Such people are unlikely to be involved in business and manufacturing innovation, which the innovation index measures. In chemistry and medicine/physiology Nobels there is more of a mix of very theoretical work and work with more immediate applications.

Comment: @DavidHammen: for Nobel prizes there are other systematic factors into the same direction. The breakthrough must be recognized, and for the Nobel prize that breakthrough must be basically in pure science, but it must also have lead to greatest benefit to humankind. I.e., tangible application results. This takes time. In addition, the awardee must be alive. Both together increases likelihood for old people being awarded for comparatively early breakthroughs. Also, old scientists tend to be managers of young scientists - who may be longer alive to be rewarded for their part in the breakthrough.

Answer (score 6):

There are a number of factors.

- Orthogonality, part I. The categories covered by the Nobel Prizes are a bit orthogonal to the concerns covered by the Innovation Index. The Nobel Peace Prize and the Nobel Prize for Literature are completely orthogonal to the concerns of the groups that decide on the Innovation Index. The science prizes (physics, chemistry, and physiology or medicine), while the basis for innovation, for the most part are not what the groups that decide the Innovation Index. The Innovation Index looks in part at advancements in engineering and computation, neither of which has a Nobel Prize.
- Orthogonality, part II. The Nobel Prizes are awarded to individuals. The Innovation Index is based on countries.
- Orthogonality, part III. The Nobel Prizes in the sciences are a bit laggy, where "a bit" can mean multiple decades of lag between discovery and award. An extreme example is Alain Aspect, whose work 48 years ago was specifically cited in the 2022 Nobel Prize in Physics. The Innovation Index tries to be more current.

Answer (score 2):

I would say there are factors in play that causes that. First is the fact that not everything that is considered innovative is worthy of a Nobel prize. Second is the fact that it could take many years for the potential of a new invention to be fully recognized for what it is. Finally there is the limited amount of Nobel prizes compared to the number of innovations each year. It doesn't matter if one country has 10 amazing new innovations if a country with a single one is considered more worthy of a Nobel prize.

In the end it boils down to which ideas are considered the most worthy of a Nobel prize and how quickly it is recognized as that over how many get produced.